# JQUERY + Find all <img> with an empty src tag

Tags: jquery

I have a number of questions users answer. An unanswered question will have a blank source like shown below:

```
 <img src="" id="joinEmailResponse" class="joinResponse" alt="...">
```

I need to be update all empty src tags with 'images/redcross.jpg' and make them visible .show();

I'm toying with the following code but its not something I done much off:

```
 var notAnswered = $('img.joinResponse').filter('[src=""]');
```

Not sure if I'm on the right track or how I would then update the src and visibility.
Would I then loop through the results or can I change the 2 modifications.

Any advise would be greatly appreciated.

thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
$('img.joinResponse[src=""]').attr("src", "images/redcross.jpg").show();
```

Answer (score 4):

Just off the top of my head, try this:

```
$(".joinResponse").each(function() {
    if($(this).attr("src") === "") {
        $(this).attr("src", "images/redcross.jpg");
    }
});
```

Somebody correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("img[src='']").attr('src','images/redcross.jpg').show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Closely related, this is how you find img nodes with no src at all

```
$("img:not([src])")
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers seem to be correct.

Elliot Bonneville is not considering img tag. It selects all tags.

dku.rajkumar and Raminson not considering class. They are selecting all images with empty src.

Here's the correct version.

```
$('img[src=""].joinResponse').attr("src", "images/redcross.jpg").show();
```